# Write a function that receives two Int’s at the input and changes their values, and at the same time doubles them

Tags: swift, function

I ask for help, I’ve already broken my whole brain. It seems that I understand that it is not a very difficult task. I read the documentation and searched the Internet for a long time.

**Write a function that receives two Int’s at the input and changes their values, and at the same time doubles them**

Comment: "changes their values" How? Doubling them?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that changing their value means swapping them and then doubling. If that is the case, you can write your own function:

```
func swapAndDouble(a: Int, b: Int) -> (Int, Int) {

    let returnTupple = (2*b, 2*a)

    return returnTupple
}
```

Then with this call:

```
let (first, second) = swapAndDouble(a: 3, b: 7)
```

You have the result.

Alternatively, if you want to use the function later for other values there is a standard swap function in the standard Swift library.

```
func swap<T>(_ a: inout T, _ b: inout T)
```

Please, read the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1540890-swap) for this.